# python list comprehension in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

```
def square100():
  d = {f"{x}" : f"{x**2}" for x in range(101)}
  print(d)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  quadrado100()
```

this function return the values in ascending order.

```
def square100():
  d = {f"{x} : {x**2}" for x in range(101)}
  print(d)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  quadrado100()
```

but this function that should do the same thing, shows in a random order.
does anyone know why?

nothing to say here

Comment: In Python, dictionnary are unordered. Sometimes it could be print in the right order but not each time!

Comment: @AdrienDerouene Since 3.8 dictionaries retain their insertion order.

Comment: Your second example isn't a dictionary, it's a set of `x : y` strings. Sets don't remember their order.

Comment: You don't have any list comprehensions in your code. A list comprehension, like an ordinary list, is inside `[]`, not `{}`.

Comment: @Barmar: The guarantee actually began with 3.7 (though all existing 3.6 compatible interpreters, CPython and PyPy, use insertion-ordered `dict`s as an implementation detail).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latter is a `set` comprehension, not a `dict` comprehension (neither one is a `list` comprehension); the difference is that there is no `:` (at top level, outside string quotes and the like) separating a key from a value in a `set` literal or comprehension, while there is one in a `dict` literal or comprehension.

`set`s have arbitrary order (effectively random for strings; it will change between different runs of Python, and can change even within a single run of Python based on the order in which items are added and removed), while `dict`s (in 3.6 as an implementation detail, and in 3.7+ as a language guarantee) are insertion-ordered. So your first bit of a code (a `dict` comprehension) retains order, while the latter, based on `set`s, does not.